# XML Output in Tornado

Tags: tornado

I am trying to output some results in Tornado in XML format. I built a test Tornado script in python, but am not getting expected results.
Here is a snippet of the script:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, tostring, dump

class myCustomHandler(myBaseHandler):
    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def _initialize(self):
            root = Element('root')
            child = SubElement(root, "child")
            child.text = "I am a child"

            res = tostring(root)
            print ('res = ' + res)
            raise tornado.gen.Return(res)

    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
            response = yield self._initialize()
            print ('response = ' + str(response))
            self.clear()
            self.finish(response)
```

The browser output I get is:

> "I am a child"

whereas the output I am expecting is:

> <root><child>I am a child</child></root>

I get this output on console from those print statement, but not on the browser. The print statements are my debugging. Changing the finish statement to write doesn't help either.

Answer (score 4):

The default `Content-Type` in Tornado is `text/html`. When you return any other kind of response, you must set the header yourself, e.g. `self.set_header('Content-Type', 'text/xml')`

Answer (score 0):

Writing output in Tornado is accomplished with the write method. Change your print to self.write.

http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html?highlight=write#tornado.web.RequestHandler.write

Comment: Correct. The print statements are just for me to debug & see the output in Tornado. My desire is to output to browser window using the self.finish() command.